# MvcSitemapProvider parameters sometimes works sometimes not

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, mvcsitemapprovider

I am using MvcSitemapProvider in my MVC4 application. My controlleractions need parameters to resolve 1:n relations in a database. For example: Shop > Item > ItemDetails. Lets say the user watches details of ItemXYZ and clicks on Shop > **Item** > ItemDetails I want the application to display ItemXYZ again. So MvcSitemapProvider would have to store the itemID. The strange behaviour is that when I change any code, run it -> it works. If I stop it, restart it(with exactly the same code) it does not work. If I change any code again -> it works again. So how is that possible. This is my sitemap-config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<mvcSiteMap xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-4.0"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-4.0 MvcSiteMapSchema.xsd">

  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Werk" controller="Settlement" action="Index">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Abteilung" controller="Section" action="Index" preservedRouteParameters="settlementID" inheritedRouteParameters="settlementID">
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="Maschine" controller="Machine" action="Index" preservedRouteParameters="sectionID" inheritedRouteParameters="sectionID"/>
    </mvcSiteMapNode>
  </mvcSiteMapNode>

</mvcSiteMap>
```

And this is a controller(all look quite the same):

```
public class SectionController : ControllerBase
{
    //
    // GET: /Section/

    [SiteMapPreserveRouteData]
    public ActionResult Index(int settlementID)
    {
        using (var e = new ClapEntities())
        {
            return View(e.Sections.Where(x => x.SettlementID == settlementID).ToList());
        }
    }
}
```

This is a working code unless I don't restart the application. If I restart the application it does not work. But if I comment e.g. the [SiteMapPreserveRouteData]-Attribute it will work once more. So I restart the application and i does not work anymore -> uncomment the Attribute and it works again until I restart it.

So how is that possible?

EDIT:
It does not has anything to do with changing code. It works when I select rebuild in the visual studio menu. If not it won't work twice.

Comment: FYI - I have made my case (for the 2nd time) with Maarten about removing SiteMapPreserveRouteDataAttribute from the project. After analyzing it carefully, I don't see how it could possibly do anything useful. I recommend against its usage.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into something like this.  I had to do 2 things:

1. Specify the `settlementID` route parameter of the parent node **Item** in the `preservedRouteParameters` attribute of the **ItemDetails** child node.  As per the [docs](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Defining-sitemap-nodes-in-XML) inheritedRouteParameters won't suffice:

   ```
   <mvcSiteMapNode title="Maschine" controller="Machine" action="Index" preservedRouteParameters="settlementID,sectionID"/>
   ```
2. Make sure that all the preservedRouteParameters are present in the action method.  I'm not sure what your **ItemsDetails** action method looks like but it needs to look something like this:

   ```
   public ActionResult Index(int settlementID, int sectionID)
   {
       //....
   }
   ```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what example you are following, but this configuration has some issues:

1. inheritedRouteParameters is for inheriting a parameter from the parent node (mvcSiteMapNode). Your example shows that the settlementID is part of the SectionController, not SettlementController so there is no need to inherit it.
2. You are using both preservedRouteParameters and SiteMapPreserveRouteDataAttribute. These are not meant to be used at the same time.

Also, be sure you have the latest version (currently 4.0.6), because there have been some node matching bug fixes since the official release.

If you fix these and you still have problems, please create a small demo project that reproduces the behavior and either post it on GitHub or zip it and make it available for download, then [open a new issue](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/issues?state=open) and post the location of your demo so we can take a look.

**UPDATE**

I reread your question and noticed that you are trying to display products from a database. Using preservedRouteParameters is only useful for the SiteMapPath (breadcrumb) HTML helper when you have navigation based on a list or table of database data. It is used to force every id to match a single node by copying the value of the parameter from the current HTTP request.

However, unless there are actual nodes added to the sitemap for each product, you will not be able to view them in other HTML helpers such as Menu or SiteMap, and more importantly, they won't appear in the `/sitemaps.xml` endpoint for search engines.

I am guessing you want your products indexed in search engines, so I recommend that you instead use [dynamic node providers](http://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Defining-sitemap-nodes-using-IDynamicNodeProvider) to load your nodes from your database into the sitemap. This will store them all in a shared cache, so it is very efficient and they won't be "forgotten" between requests. Just be sure to set the id of each product by using `node.RouteValues.Add("id", product.id)` so there is a unique ID to make a match on.

Comment: Well I fixed that but there is still exactly the same behavior. If I select rebuild it works once. @NightOwl888

Comment: oh and I am using nuget... should be the latest version

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice your comments before. I have updated my answer.